# Являются ли части сложноподчинённого предложения однородными?

Tags: пунктуация, спп

Не могу понять, являются ли части сложноподчинённого предложения однородными или нет. Соответственно, не могу понять, нужна ли запятая перед "и".

> Уверен, что твое счастье не за горами(,) и ты найдёшь мужчину, который
>   сделает для тебя всё.

Comment: А как вы рассуждаете?

Comment: Роман, если вы хотите выразить уверенность в обоих суждениях, то отсутствие запятой как раз и говорит об этом. В этом случае оба последних предложения читаются в одну фразу, а запятая будет разъединять их.

Answer (score 2):

В данном случае части СПП являются однородными. Запятая не нужна. Уверен, что счастье не за горами; уверен,  что ты найдешь своего мужчину.

Уверен, что твое счастье не за горами и ты найдёшь мужчину, который сделает для тебя всё.

Comment: То есть по сути эта запятая на письме влияет на смысл предложения? Изначальная мысль автора - уверенность в обоих суждениях, то есть запятую ставить не хочу. Нет ли какого-нибудь правила/принципа, что если предложение можно разбить ("вытащить" из него подчинённую часть), то лучше так и сделать? Для упрощения восприятия, так сказать

Comment: Я не вижу здесь никакой сложносочиненной связи, осложненной подчинением. Более того, мне вообще неизвестна такая формулировка. Здесь однородные придаточные. Поэтому запятая не нужна. Других правил нет.

Answer (score 1):

К сожалению, после ответа Сержа вряд ли можно услышать логику автора. 
Поэтому отвечаю вариативно.

> Не могу понять, являются ли части сложноподчинённого предложения
>   однородными или нет.

А это и невозможно понять, не привнося некоторых допущений. Если вы считаете, что здесь действительно два подчиненных одному слову "уверен" предложения, то они однородны и запятой не надо. *Но даже в этом случае запятая перед "что" необходима (у Сержа была ошибка, которую он, слава богу исправил)*.

А вот если вы рассматриваете предложение как сложносочиненное, одна из частей которого осложнена подчиненным, то есть, если "уверен" относится только к первой части, то запятая требуется. Мне в данном случае субъективно ближе именно этот вариант, с переменой мест получаем:

*Ты найдёшь мужчину, который сделает для тебя всё, и уверен, что твое счастье не за горами.*

Как-то вот такая трактовка естественнее, первый вариант я изначально даже не рассматривал (согласен, несколько погорячился).
Таким образом, оба варианта возможны, я тяготею к запятой:

***Уверен, что твое счастье не за горами, и ты найдёшь мужчину, который сделает для тебя всё*.**